# Trying to get a whole table row to highlight on mouseover

Tags: css, hover

I have a gradient row in a table, and I would like to change the gradient of the entire row when the mouse is over any cell in that row. As far as I've been able to read, the CSS I'm using now should work, but nothing happens upon mouseover (but the original gradient looks perfect). Here is the CSS:

```
td {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.silvergrad {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFF', endColorstr='#CCC');
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#CCC));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #CCC);
}

.silvergrad tr:hover td {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#999', endColorstr='#CCC');
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#999), to(#CCC));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #999, #CCC);
}
```

I have tried it with and without the td after the .silvergrad tr:hover.
Here is the HTML for the row:

```
<tr class="silvergrad">
  <td>Some stuff</td>
  <td>Some stuff</td>
  <td>Some stuff</td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Change your one CSS rule from:

```
.silvergrad tr:hover td {
```

to

```
.silvergrad:hover td {
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hULbd/)**

There is no `tr` element that's a descendant of `.silvergrad`. `silvergrad` *is* the `tr`.

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying the table row as a descendant of the element with the silvergrad class, whereas it *is* the element with the silvergrad class. Try using this:

```
tr.silvergrad:hover td {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#999', endColorstr='#CCC');
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#999), to(#CCC));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #999, #CCC);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is looking for a `tr` that is *inside* an element with the `.silvergrad` class, not for one that has it. Try this:

```
tr.silvergrad:hover>td
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its changing but you cant see.

please try this for gradient code.

```
.silvergrad tr:hover>td{

 background-color: #999;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #999, #ccc);
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#999), to(#ccc));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #999, #ccc);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #999, #ccc);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #999, #ccc);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff999',endColorstr='#ffccc', GradientType=0);
}
```

please reply after testing :)

Answer (score 0):

Now it works, although I could SWEAR this is one of the many variations I tried. All I did was to change:

```
.silvergrad tr:hover td {
```

to simply

```
.silvergrad:hover {
```

and now it works beautifully. Thanks to all of you who responded so quickly.